# Express route returning no value as function is not executed

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, vue.js, express

I am struggling with some Express routs that behave differently even though the code to execute is the same.

I want a client application to call the API as follows:

```
async search(){

      const query = this.$refs.searchInput.value;
      console.log(query);

      const addressToFetch = "/api/budget/search?q=" + query;
      await fetch(addressToFetch)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Where the value of `query` is taken from the following input HTML tag:

```
              <div class="input-group row text-right">
                <!--flex-nowrap-->
                <div class="col">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="searchInput"
                    name="search"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    ref="searchInput"
                  />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-search btn-filter"
                    @click="search"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger"
                    v-if="filteredResults"
                    @click="getExpenses"
                  >
                    Undo
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The server-side application handles the request as follows:

```
app.get("/api/budget/search", verify, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.q);
  const users = await db
    .collection("users")
    .find({ username: { $regex: req.query.q } })
    .toArray();
  users.forEach((user) => {
    delete user.password;
  });

  res.json(users);
});
```

After authentication, this function returns `[]` and not even server-side logs are printed. Checking with Postman, I can see that the response is 200 OK anyway. I created a different route for testing purposes with the same code inside. It turns out that the new route gives different (good) results:

```
app.get("/api/users/search", verify, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.q);
  const users = await db
    .collection("users")
    .find({ username: { $regex: req.query.q } })
    .toArray();
  users.forEach((user) => {
    delete user.password;
  });

  res.json(users);
});
```

I leave you all the routes to see if there are any problems with it:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const session = require("express-session");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const exp = require("constants");
const uri = "mongodb://mongohost";
const app = express();

const client = new MongoClient(uri);
let db = null;

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "segreto",
    resave: false,
  })
);

function verify(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403);
  }
}

app.post("/api/auth/signup", async (req, res) => {});

app.post("/api/auth/signin", async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget/whoami", verify, (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget/:year", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget/:year/:month", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget/:year/:month/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.post("/api/budget/:year/:month", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.put("/api/budget/:year/:month/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.delete("/api/budget/:year/:month/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/balance", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/balance/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.get("/api/budget/search", verify, async (req, res) => {...});


app.get("/api/users/search", verify, async (req, res) => {...});

app.listen(3000, async () => {
  await client.connect();
  db = client.db("balanceApp");
});
```

I don't get the problem with the first route, is there anything I can do to fix the problem? Thank you very much for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express uses the [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) package to match your route paths.

When you make `GET` request to

```html
/api/budget/search
```

the path-to-regexp package gets the path as `/api/budget/search` and as express goes through your routes top-to-bottom looking for a match it hits:

```js
app.get("/api/budget/:year", verify, async (req, res) => {...});
```

Now path-to-regexp has a `keys` array with objects each containing a `name` property that holds your request parameters. It must have parsed your word `search` and interpreted that as the request parameter `:year` so as far as express is concerned `/api/budget/search` matches `/api/budget/:year` so it routes the request to here.

All you have to do is move this route:

```js
app.get("/api/budget/search", verify, async (req, res) => {...});
```

above this route:

```js
app.get("/api/budget/:year", verify, async (req, res) => {...});
```

so that express has a chance to make an exact pattern match.

Answer (score 2):

You have a route /api/budget/:year which matches /api/budget/search, it must have fallen into this handler instead

Comment: This is correct.